# mouse listener not working in card panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

i want to add mouselistener to card panel but it is not working....i want to code that when mouse enters card panel ,images change automatically, and they stop moving when mouse exits card panel....three images are added to card panel cp1

```
public class entry extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
CardLayout clayout1;
Panel p4,p5,p6,cp1;
String s2[]={"fourth","fifth","sixth"};
boolean x;

entry()
{
setLayout(null);
    cp1=new Panel();
    clayout1=new CardLayout();
    cp1.setLayout(clayout1);
    cp1.setBounds(0,0,1920,500);
    cp1.addMouseListener(this);  //here iam adding mouselistener to cardpanel

    p4=new Panel();
    img4=new ImageIcon("a.jpg");
    l4=new JLabel(img4);
    p4.add(l4);

    p5=new Panel();
    img5=new ImageIcon("b.jpg");
    l5=new JLabel(img5);
    p5.add(l5);

    p6=new Panel();
    img6=new ImageIcon("3.jpg");
    l6=new JLabel(img6);
    p6.add(l6);

    add(cp1);
    cp1.add(p4,"fourth");
    cp1.add(p5,"fifth");
    cp1.add(p6,"sixth");
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    { 
         x=true;

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){
            clayout1.show(cp1,s2[i]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException E) {

                E.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(i==2){
                i=-1;}
            System.out.println("entered");  //this "entered" is not being printed in console    
            if(x)
            {
            break;  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use Thread.sleep in an event handler. Don't use an infinite loop in an event handler. - If you want to start some activity to be continued after sensing an event, start a thread.

Comment: As already stated, the use of `Thread.sleep(...)`, in the code, is simply blocking the `Event Dispatcher Thread - EDT`, which is responsible for rendering artifacts, hence the result. Instead use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), for doing such thingy

Comment: Don't use `null` layouts, you don't control the properties which will effect the amount of space a component might need on different platforms. Make use of appropriate lay out managers

Comment: You will want to do some research into `javax.swing.Timer`, which will allow you to perform animation safely in Swing

Comment: Just the infinite loop so created, is actually blocking the `EDT`, even if you remove `Thread.sleep(...)`. In it's presence, even other events are not fired (GUI freezes)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sleeping on the `Event Dispatcher Thread - EDT` which is responsible for rendering the Swing artifacts on to the screen, by using `Thread.sleep(...)`, you should be using [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), as shown in the code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutExample {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    private Timer timer;

    private String[] cardNames = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    private Random random;
    private int count;

    private static final int GAP = 5;    

    private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            count %= cardNames.length;
            CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
            layout.show(contentPane, cardNames[count++]);
        }
    };

    public CardLayoutExample() {
        random = new Random();
        count = 0;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("CardLayoutExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = getPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(GAP, GAP));
        contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
                if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.start();
                }                
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < cardNames.length; i++) {
            contentPane.add(getPanel(), cardNames[i]);
        }

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(1000, timerAction);        
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 200);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(getRandomColor());

        return panel;
    }

    private Color getRandomColor() {
        return new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(),
                            random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CardLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: CardLayoutAnimation]

Answer (score 0):

Of course your "entered" is not being printed - you created an infinite loop immediately before it in your event handler. Remove that and the call to `Thread.sleep` and you'll print it.

Comment: i've removed thread.sleep()...even now "entered" is not being printed @chris